# Some labels and UITextfiled and it's text becoming black automatically when selecting Dark Dode

Tags: swift5

I am migrated my all code to swift 5 and Xcode 11 recently,
My app works fine for iOS versions below 13.0 but when I chose Dark Mode, the labels are going black, some textfields and it's text automatically shown black, all of has white background and app theme is in white background and it is very hard to reset it from storyboard.

Anyone has any trick to do it in app delegate or in viewdidload to turn off the dark mode for this particular app? I don't want to take the facility of dark mode right now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it in one line of code to eliminate the dark mode entirely by setting the UserInterfaceStyle on main window:

```
window!.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
```

or you can do it in

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    window!.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
}
```